# view getTop() returns different values when switching between views

Tags: android

I have been trying to calculate listview vertical offset. I am using an expandable listview and using view.getTop() method inside my onScroll method. Everything works fine, except the fact that getTop() returns negative values initially (which is correct), but as soon the switching between views take place, it returns positive values at the time of switch. After that, it works normally returning negative values. I'm fetching these values for the topmost view in the list (getChildAt(0)). Any reasons for this behavior? Due to this, I'm getting erroneous results in my calculations. Thanks.